# sqlplus exit and pass any number

Tags: sqlplus, exit

I spotted that the exit function of sqlplus is supposed to work with variables and bind variables. In the end, even the "exit success" and "exit failure" option combined with an if-decision would do the job. I have tried some variation of:

test.sql:

```
L_return INT;
l_return:=test_func_returns_1();
exit l_return;
/
```

But this all did not run properly. I guess, once I wrap my code with an anonymous block, the exit will not work anymore, right? Can you help me?
Many greetings,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it rather was the issue with Variables than with the EXIT. A combination of bind variables, output parameters, and the abbreviation of an anonymous block works:

test_package:

```
procedure test (some_var OUT INT) As
begin
   some_var:= 77;
end;
```

test.sql:

```
variable my_var number
execute test_package.test(:my_var)
exit :my_var
/
```

test.cmd

```
call sqlplus %dbuser% test.sql
echo Result %errorlevel% >> %log%
```

log

```
Result 77
```

PS: according to https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables#3 it should be possible to define bind variables globally and set them inside an anonymous block. but I ran into an error doing so.